# In Flutter for web, I can't initialize Firebase into my project

Tags: flutter, dart, web

[image]

I added the necessary files in pubspec.yaml. But when I try to start firebase in main.dart it stops the project and shows an error in painter.dart.

Comment: You have the proper Firebase configuration in your index.html?

Comment: yes i added script codes